# File transfer through API for larger files

Tags: json, shell, curl, api-design, file-transfer

As a solution to a problem, I'm trying to build a simple API that will allow files to be transferred to a particular server.

The file will be encoded into base64 and the resulting string will be included as one of the values in some Json.  The API will be called with cURL on the client side.

On the server side the appropriate value will be decoded and the file will be recovered.

I wonder: is this a good approach? I assume there must be a better way to do this (ideally using minimal / shell tools rather than any particular language), as I think this approach will not scale well with file size. Furthermore, I am new to thinking about this problem and some of my assumptions may be faulty or I may be unaware of something that could be a big help in this area.

Comment: You'll do well to study the history and design of existing file transfer systems/protocols. `ftp` morphed into `sftp` (using "secure shell" to encrypt the transmission, (that is the leading `s`) ). `kermit` is also a fading file transfer protcol, there are numerous others, and when you bring in legacy technology (mainframes) there are even more. In any case, open ended Qs like this are off-topic. You might try searching for an appropriate internet news group for this discussion or post to Quora.com . Good luck.

Comment: Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter Aside from both involving file transfer, sftp and ftp are different, unrelated protocols.

Comment: @Shawn . Yep I don't dispute that. My emphasis was meant to be on the O.P.'s need to dig into history and design of file transfer protocols, rather that reinvent the wheel. There's only so much time for comments. Thanks for clarifying that! Good luck go all.